# Xcode gives an error "Unrecognized selector sent to instance”

Tags: ios, swift

I try to make an calculator app, just to get closer to the Swift syntax. 
Everything worked just fine, until I tried to implement sqrt function which I make with switch statement for usability of the other symbols I will include.

Suddenly I am getting SIGABRD error after including a performOperation method.
Am I missing something? I really cannot find anything.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    @IBAction func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!

        if display.text! == "0" {
            display.text! = digit
        } else {
            display.text! = display.text! + digit
        }
    }

    var displayValue: Double {
        get {
            return Double(display.text!)!
        }

        set {
            display.text = String(newValue)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func performOperation(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let mathematicalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
            switch mathematicalSymbol {
            case "√":
                print("Hello")
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: has the IBAction been connected to the storyboard/nib properly?

Comment: I connected it using the control + drag from the button. So I hope it is right. Button contains symbol "√"

Comment: This type of error mostly come when you are not done proper linking with xib components with code (ui components and actions method) please check those.

Comment: which line it will give error, if you done connection right way

Comment: I just attempted to add it again. I get SIGABRT errro, and console outputs "(lldb)". Sadly it doesn't show me which line throws the error... although that is possible, because I am new to the xcode IDE, I will do a quick Gsearch.
But I suppose, it dies in the "performOperation" function, since the number input works fine, and app dies only when I hit square root button which calls "performOperation"

Comment: Please copy and paste the full error message into your question instead of trying to describe it.  It should include both the selector name and the data type.

Comment: ```
2020-02-23 15:46:10.787742+0100 WonderCalc[5481:511821] -[WonderCalc.ViewController addOperation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145e070e0
2020-02-23 15:46:10.788447+0100 WonderCalc[5481:511821] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[WonderCalc.ViewController addOperation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x145e070e0'
```

Now I noticed it talks about addOperation, which I had specified before, but I took it away. Is there some special way to clean up old deleted functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception reason (you should always include those errors in the question) in the comments there is a dead connection in Interface Builder

- Press <kbd>⇧⌘F</kbd>
- Search for <kbd>addOperation</kbd>
- Click on the search result
- Delete the connection in Interface Builder

If nothing is found press <kbd>⇧⌘K</kbd> to clean the project

Comment: Thank you so much! 

I will definitely include, error message next time, how silly of me... Thanks to anyone for having the patience for me!

I had no idea that dead connections needed to be also removed from storyboards. Good to know. Thanks a lot!